# IIS 7.0 Error - 500.19 Internal Server Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, hosting

I am currently on a shared hosting plan with iis 7.0

I have an asp.net mvc application in the wwwroot of my hosting. Now I made a virtual directory to store my webservice in(I don't want to have to host this on a sub domain and pay extra)

However when I put my web service code in my virtual directory and try to run it I get this

```
Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x80070005
Config Error    Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
Config File \\?\C:\HostingSpaces\int\Site.com\wwwroot\web.config
Requested URL   http://www.Site.com:80/VirtualDirectory/Webservice.asmx
Physical Path   C:\HostingSpaces\int\Site.com\wwwroot\VirutalDirectory\Webservice.asmx
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined
Config Source

   -1: 
    0:
```

I don't know what the probelm is nor how to fix it.

Comment: In my case ASP .NET State Service has been turned off. So turn it on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should check the permission of the user account of the apppool.
Or you can check the security property of the folder(C:\HostingSpaces\int\Site.com\wwwroot). Ensure the account of the apppool of IIS can read the folder at least.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be due to IIS needing an extra plugin like the `URL rewrite module rule`

Comment: This was the case for me.  Good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You have your permissions set incorrectly. From within DotNetPanel go to the file manager and set the permissions for the virtual directory by clicking the "Lock" icon.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot read configuration file due to
>   insufficient permissions

This sounds like the file is unreadable by the user that runs the web server. I am not sure what kind of tools Windows hosting serivce provides, but you will need to set permissions on that enitre directory to be readable by the web server user.

Comment: My hosting company uses dot net panel.I am not sure who this user you are referring too. I will check it out. It's kinda weird that if I make a subdomain and put my asp.net-mvc application and a virtual directory with my webservice it works. I don't know why maybe it is because I only have one virtual directory in my subdomain so I have to try with another virtual directory to rule that out.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `IIS_IUSR` User for the folder and give the Read and Execute access. I was facing the same problem and after giving the permissions I was able to access the Website without any issues