# "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" when trying to host a website in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I followed the steps in part 4 [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0#DeployonIIS7) to try and host a web site locally but I keep getting the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.

First I tried entering the physical directory as the folder where my visual studio project is stored, since it contains the web pages anyway and it is a work in progress (to avoid having to republish every time). This didn't work so I then published the site to the wwwroot folder and changed the physical directory to this but it gave me the same error.

I read the problem could have something to do with which framework version the application pool uses, but I tried it with both v2 and v4 and keep getting the same error (p.s. how do I check which version I *should* be using?).

This is the first time I'm trying this and I am quite lost, any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I removed the following code from my web.config

And am now presented with the following error

> HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL)
>   configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web
>   server.

EDIT 2: When I try browse a web page on my site, say http://localhost/SponsorAChild/Login.aspx I now get the following error:

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note
>   that attribute names are case-sensitive.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 16:  Line 17:    Line 18:      Line 19:      Line 20:

Like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530725/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen) But changing the application pool to one which uses the v4 framework gives the first 500.19 error again

Comment: the same error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054582/iis-7-0-error-500-19-internal-server-error

Comment: Could be due to permissions on the folder on server which contains your ASP.NET website - it needs to have IUSER or NETWORK SERVICE, I think, with read and execute permissions.

Answer (score 0):

After you got the Error 500.19, did you run this command?

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```