# IIS7 Website Configuration [Server Error 500.19]

Tags: iis-7, web-config, windows-server-2008

I created a Windows Server 2008 virtual box with IIS7. I have two websites configured, one is my actual development site and the second is a test site to help troubleshoot this issue.

Website 1 (WS1) - the root of this website is on a drive which is mapped to my development machine (Mac Book Pro). The mapping seems to be working and I can access all files fine (W:\www\dev.frogquest.com).

Website 2 (WS2) - is a very simple website with one ColdFusion page just to prove that everything works. It's root is a local directory on the C:\ drive of the VB (C:\sites\localtestsite.com).

I've added host file entries for both sites (127.0.0.1   ...)

WS1 - Throws a Server error when I try to access it...

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

Here's what I've tried so far...

1. Uninstalled both .NET  4.5 and URL Rewrite 2, rebooted, reinstalled .NET 4.5, rebooted, reinstalled URL Rewrite 2 Module… retried… FAIL! I took these actions because of information I found here...
   [HTTP Error 500.19 on IIS7 "Malformed XML" in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132029/http-error-500-19-on-iis7-malformed-xml-in-web-config)
2. Per the same article as above, I tried deleting the web.config file. Strangely, this had no impact, even after restarting the website, restarting the virtual box instance, etc... which I've done frequently btw just to rule that out.
3. I tried adding IIS_IUSRS to the WS1 directory, but because it's a mapped drive I didn't get a "Security" tab. So, this was fruitless. This was per this article...
   [IIS 7.0 Error - 500.19 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054582/iis-7-0-error-500-19-internal-server-error)
4. I tried playing with the AppPool security, changing it from "pass-through authentication" to connecting as the administrator of the machine. When I clicked "Test Settings" I did get different results, but they didn't have any material affect in the actual server response. I have screenshots of the test setting results.
5. I copied the contents of WS1 into WS2 and this works! So, it has something to do with the fact that it's a mapped drive and very likely a permissioning issue in my opinion.

I am now out of ideas and in need of competent help and fresh ways of thinking about this!

UPDATE: Adding a screenshot of the actual error for more info...
[image]

Comment: The 500.19 page does not only give you such limited info, but usually a file name and the line number. If you are reluctant to provide that, readers like me will be reluctant to reply further.

Comment: Thanks for your input and reply, @LexLi. I've edited the description to with a screenshot of the actual error and all the info it entails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS does not support any type of mapped drive,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257174

You will have to use the recommended workarounds, such as UNC paths.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi. I wasn't able to figure out how to map from Windows to a Mac Share via UNC. This would be ideal, so if you have any specific suggestions on how to make that connection, I'd love to hear them. For now, I've worked around the issue by creating c:\sites\dev.frogquest.com, copying the files in there, and setting the site root to that local file system. I'm using BitTorrentSync (getsync.com) to syncronize the files from  my mac to that windows directory. It's a bit hackish, but it'll get me through my immediate need. I would very much like to share the directory itself instead tho

Comment: @ChrisGeirman a normal way might be using samba, but I think your current approach of using BitTorrentSync looks ok.